# How to store the file path with id in the mysql database?

Tags: jquery, mysql, ajax, codeigniter

I have done image upload in code-igniter with jquery,ajax.It works fine.Whats my question is after uploading image ,uploaded image name is stored in table.But i want id of the image to be stored along with filename of the image(i.e)1 img1.jpg.For this what i have to do.any one help me to solve this.

**Ajax add code:**

```
public function ajax_add()
    {
        $this->_validate();

        $data = array(
                'firstName'     => $this->input->post('firstName'),
                'lastName'      => $this->input->post('lastName'),
                'email'         => $this->input->post('email'),
                'phone'         => $this->input->post('phone'),
                'address'       => $this->input->post('address'),
                'password'      => $this->input->post('password'),
                'status'        => $this->input->post('status'),
                'createddate'   => $this->input->post('createddate'),
                'updateddate'   => $this->input->post('updateddate'),

            );

        if(!empty($_FILES['photo']['name']))
        {
            $upload = $this->_do_upload();
            $data['photo'] = $upload;
        }

        $insert = $this->person->save($data);

        echo json_encode(array("status" => TRUE));
    }
```

**Image upload code:**

```
private function _do_upload()
    {
        $config['upload_path']          = 'upload/';
        $config['allowed_types']        = 'gif|jpg|png|jpeg|pdf';
        $config['max_size']             = 1000; //set max size allowed in Kilobyte
        $config['max_width']            = 1000; // set max width image allowed
        $config['max_height']           = 1000; // set max height allowed
        $new_name = $_FILES["photo"]['name'];
        $config['file_name'] = $new_name;
        //$config['file_name']            = round(microtime(true) * 1000); //just milisecond timestamp fot unique name

        $this->load->library('upload', $config);

        if(!$this->upload->do_upload('photo')) //upload and validate
        {
            $data['inputerror'][] = 'photo';
            $data['error_string'][] = 'Upload error: '.$this->upload->display_errors('',''); //show ajax error
            $data['status'] = FALSE;
            echo json_encode($data);
            exit();
        }
        return $this->upload->data('file_name');
    }
```

Comment: not understand what you want

Comment: I to want store the uploaded image name with id prepend to the name in database.

Comment: then use last inserted id

Comment: can u highlight where i have to use that?

Comment: i am a beginner so only i am asking can u?

Comment: see below mentioned ans

Comment: Why not prepend the id on the filename when you select (use) it? Are you searching on the filename with the id in the database?

Comment: prepend the id like this format in the db.now what i have(img.jpg) for the id 1.

Comment: but i want like this (1_img.jpg) in the database.

Comment: @Rameshwar are u der...

Comment: y u remove ur answer

Comment: i want the answer...u have to help me to solve this forme...

Comment: @HariFrais see i added new ans

Comment: @HariFrais please use this and get value to last inserted database.
$this->db->insert_id();